# Java program hangs when trying to invoke powershell script

Tags: java, powershell, netbeans

I'm building a GUI with NetBeans, and one of the buttons in the GUI requires the use of a powershell script. I'm trying to get the script's output and put it into a JTextArea within the GUI. Here is what I have so far. I did a bit of debugging, and it seems to hang inside the while loop, but I'm confused as to why it's doing so.

```
private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("cmd powershell C:/hello1.ps1");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            outputTextArea.setText(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BatchFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And here is a simple powershell script I'm trying to get it to work with.

```
#Filename: hello1.ps1
Write-Host "Hello World!"
#End of Script
```

I did some researched, and I noticed that it was hanging for other people to, but only because they forgot to close the processes output stream.

Comment: Why are you launching the command processor to launch Powershell? Also, it may be better to launch Powershell in non-interactive mode (e.g. `powershell -NoLogo -Noninteractive C:/hello1.ps1`)

Comment: I agree with @ig0774 on both points. Adding cmd to the mix is just consuming time & resources, while muddying the waters and providing no benefit. Powershell.exe stands alone.

Comment: Once I get my code working, I'll take these suggestions into account. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. I moved the proc.getOutputStream().close() before the while loop and everything worked

Answer (score 1):

```
private void runButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
    String allOutput = "";                                
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("cmd /c powershell C:/hello1.ps1");
        BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader outReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
            allOutput += "\n" + line;
        }
        while ((line = outReader.readLine()) != null) {
            allOutput += "\n" + line;
        }
        int retVal = proc.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BatchFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    outputTextArea.setText(allOutput);
}
```

- Form the command line properly with CMD.EXE /c
- Check the ErrorStream
- Use Process.waitFor() read the java-docs for the Process class.
- No need to close the OutputStream since you never use it and the program shouldn't expect user input (java switching the names of input and output is annoying)

*NOTE* the code above isn't tested, so there may be syntax errors etc etc.

Comment: I've modified my code to take account of your suggestions. It's still hanging, though. I set a break point right before the first while loop. It gets to that break point, but right when it hits the first while statement it just hangs forever. This doesn't make much sense to me whatsoever. If I blatantly put errors into my powershell script, it will enter the first while loop and put the output in allOutput, but then once it finishes, it doesn't even hit the second loop, it just hangs.

Comment: I've commented out the while loops and the proce.waitFor() statement, and it doesn't hang anymore, but then this defeats the whole purpose of the program. What could be causing this?!

Comment: @Franklin - In the powershell script write-output instead of write-host is one problem, or simply the string "Hello World!" on its own line. If you really need it working now and don't have time to tinker then have your powershell script output results to a file and then read the file after the execution.

Comment: I've tried changing to write-output, but it still is hanging. I even changed the command from powershell to just a simple cmd dir command, and it still hangs. Does it have something to do with [this](http://vyvaks.wordpress.com/2006/05/27/does-runtimeexec-hangs-in-java/)

Comment: @Franklin - give the example from the link a try, I don't program in Java often (mostly because of asinine gotchyas like this). If the issue is buffering then you could also try using just the raw streams and the .available() and .read(byte[]) methods in your while loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tested code, note the choice to "hack" or close STDIN when done.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test
{
    private static boolean hack=false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        String cmd[];

        if (hack)
            cmd=new String[]{"cmd","/c","C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","-File","c:\\cygwin\\home\\jpyeron\\test.ps1", "<NUL"};
        else
            cmd=new String[]{"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","-File","c:\\cygwin\\home\\jpyeron\\test.ps1"};

        final Process p = rt.exec(cmd);

        Thread stdout = new Thread()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                InputStream out = p.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(out)); 
                String line = null; 
                try
                {
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println(line); 
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }              
            };
        };
        stdout.start();

        Thread stderr = new Thread()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                InputStream err = p.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(err)); 
                String line = null; 
                try
                {
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println(line); 
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                
            };
        };
        stderr.start();

        if (hack)
            ;
        else
            p.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me: Do not read the InputStream if there are no errors.
e.g.

```
private void takeAction () throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String action = getAction (); // A powershell-Command
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ( action );

    InputStream is = p.getErrorStream ();
    if ( 0 < is.available () )
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
                new InputStreamReader ( is ) );
        String err = br.readLine ();
        while ( null != err )
        {
            System.out.println ( "takeAction() " + err );
            err = br.readLine ();
        }
        p.getOutputStream ().close ();
    }
}
```