# Powershell script invoked from java hangs

Tags: java, powershell

I have been looking at a thread
[java input.readLine hangs after starting a powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375226/java-input-readline-hangs-after-starting-a-powershell-script)

which is exactly what I have done, but in JDK 1.6, we do not have
ProcessBuilder  - redirectOutput and Redirect to.

So is there any way to solve the waiting/hanging?

Answer (score 1):

I believe real problem is the way how PowerShell handles STDIN stream while running in Java executed console environment. I use this trick to run batch scripts with powershell task or direct powershell script execution. Add `InputFormat none` to avoid STDIN hangs.

```
powershell -NoLogo -Noninteractive -InputFormat none -Command "%cmd%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the Apache Ant library available at http://ant.apache.org/

I've used the 'Exec' task to run git.exe and capture its output. I modeled the code after the second option on http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy